# Why use useMemo and not useCallback here?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, usecallback, react-usememo

So as i understand the difference between the two is that useCallback is used if a function or object or array is returned while useMemo when a primitive is returned.
But i was looking up debouncing (this is the article: https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-throttle-debounce/ and it said useMemo would be a better solution.
With useCallback

```
import { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';
export function FilterList({ names }) {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  let filteredNames = names;
  if (query !== "") {
    filteredNames = names.filter((name) => {
      return name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());
    });
  }
  const changeHandler = event => {
    setQuery(event.target.value);
  };
  const debouncedChangeHandler = useCallback(
    debounce(changeHandler, 300)
  , []);
  return (
    <div>
      <input 
        onChange={debouncedChangeHandler} 
        type="text" 
        placeholder="Type a query..."
      />
      {filteredNames.map(name => <div key={name}>{name}</div>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

With useMemo

```
import { useState, useMemo } from 'react';
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';
export function FilterList({ names }) {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  let filteredNames = names;
  if (query !== "") {
    filteredNames = names.filter((name) => {
      return name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());
    });
  }
  const changeHandler = (event) => {
    setQuery(event.target.value);
  };
  const debouncedChangeHandler = useMemo(
    () => debounce(changeHandler, 300)
  , []);
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        onChange={debouncedChangeHandler}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Type a query..."
      />
      {filteredNames.map(name => <div key={name}>{name}</div>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And i don't understand. Is debounce returning a primitive value? If not how can we use useMemo? Also how is useMemo better than useCallback here?

Comment: `useCallback` takes a function, and returns that function memoized. `useMemo` takes a function that returns a value, runs that function, and memoizes that return value.

Answer (score 9):

First about your quote:

> useCallback is used if a function or object or array is returned while
> useMemo when a primitive is returned

No, this is wrong. `useCallback` is mainly for memoizing functions. `useMemo` helps to avoid expensive calculations.

---

Now for the article. That article prefers `useMemo` for a different reason, that of performance; although I doubt in most such cases the performance difference will be noticeable.

```
 const debouncedChangeHandler = useCallback(
    debounce(changeHandler, 300)
  , []);
```

It says:

> However... this implementation has a small performance issue: each
> time the component re-renders, **a new instance of the debounced
> function is created by the debounce(changeHandler, 300)**.

It is saying that even though the `debouncedChangeHandler` remains the same across re renders due to `useCallback`, the `debounce(changeHandler, 300)` is still executed on each render.

But with `useMemo`:

```
  const debouncedChangeHandler = useMemo(
    () => debounce(changeHandler, 300)
  , []);
```

it claims:

> useMemo(() => debounce(changeHandler, 300), []) memoizes the debounced
> handler, but also **calls debounce() only during initial rendering** of
> the component.

Because `useMemo` unlike `useCallback` doesn't directly call `debounce`, rather calls it *inside* an inline function.

---

Run this code:

```
let fakeDebounce = (param) => {
  console.log(param);
  return () => {};
};

export default function App() {
  let f = React.useCallback(fakeDebounce('test1'), []);
  let g = React.useMemo(() => fakeDebounce('test2'), []);
  let [x, setX] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => {
        setX(x + 1);
      }}
    >
      <h1>{x}</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Click `div` anywhere and see how `test2` isn't logged anymore.

Comment: Thanks but i am even more confused. I took a course in which they said this is the difference between useMemo and useCallback. Can you tell when should useMemo and useCallback be used?

Comment: @H.b Check docs: Hard to explain as comment I suggest look for info online, there should be plenty. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Comment: @giorgimoniava, Can we do something like this `useCallback(
    (e) => debounce((e) => changeHandler(e), 300)
  , []);` instead of calling the debounce inside `useCallback` every render?

Comment: @Shan that would return a *different result* as compared to `useCallback(
    debounce(changeHandler, 300),[])`. It would return a function, which you would additionally have to invoke on each render; and I am not sure that way you would benefit from using debounce.

Comment: @giorgimoniava ok, got it.

Answer (score 2):

```js
  const debouncedChangeHandler = useCallback(
    debounce(changeHandler, 300)
  , []);
```

in every render:

1. `debounce(changeHandler, 300)` will run(it is not a function, it is a called function) and resolve into a value(which is a callback)
2. then useCallback will run, check the the dependency to determine whether it should return memoized value(callback) or new value, so in your case, it will return memoized value

```js
  const debouncedChangeHandler = useMemo(
    () => debounce(changeHandler, 300)
  , [])
```

in every render

1. `() => debounce(changeHandler, 300)` will not run, it is value(callback)
2. then useMemo will run, it will check the dependency to determine whether to run the callback or not, in your case, it will not run the callback

hence useMemo are more efficient

Answer (score 0):

if you want to return a value, use **useMemo**
if you use useMemo, it will cause side effect, which makes code look bad.
if you want to return a callback,use **useCallback**